# if this condition match then return value from another column in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, match, case

if the 'minimum_nights' column matches

[image]

then return certain values from the 'host_column' column.

I filtered the `minimum_nights` column with values '> 90'.
Now, is it possible to get values from `host_location`?
just some certain values (if only outside the 'UK' region?

[attached data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fe582KHfOyQIded-8DvYM87pHHbfh8Th/view?usp=sharing)

```
airbnb1 <- airbnb1 %>%
select(host_location, minimum_nights, revenue) %>%
filter(minimum_nights > 90) %>%  
mutate(host_location = ifelse(host_location== "", 'unknown', 
host_location)) %>%
reframe(host_location, minimum_nights, revenue)
```

Comment: Hi @JayPrakash, please dont post your data as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Also, please dont add links to your data (they may go dead over time, etc), but instead add the data in as code. If you need help converting your dataset to reproducible code, [you can find help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue on my own and some help from StackOverflow.
It took me almost half of my day.

no problem if someone downvotes me, I'm keeping this post alive for someone who needed the fix as I did.

here :

airbnb_outside <- airbnb

```
airbnb_outside <- airbnb_outside %>%  
filter(minimum_nights > 90) %>% 
mutate(host_location = ifelse(host_location== "", 'unknown', host_location))
```

#### filter > mutated the 'host_column'

```
airbnb_outside<- airbnb_outside %>% 
mutate(really = if_else(str_ends(host_location, "Kingdom"), "in", "out"))
```

#### filter > mutated another 'column'

```
airbnb_outside <- airbnb_outside %>% 
select(host_location, minimum_nights, revenue, really) %>%
filter(really == 'out') %>% 
reframe(host_location, minimum_nights, revenue, really)
```

#### we have a new funny column 'really' with a new data frame 'airbnb_outside' and an original data frame 'airbnb'.

```
airbnb <- airbnb(airbnb, airbnb_outside, by = "host_location")
```

#### anti-join on original dataframe